# Problem passing data from one component to another component using services in Angular 8

Tags: arrays, angular, components, communication

Am working on a Single Page Application CRUD based API whereby am passing 
data from the frontend to the backend using JWT which works fine. On the backend am saving the data in a database and later fetching all the data and return as a response to the frontend which works fine.

On the frontend, I fetch the data in the response and pass to another component through a Service. Basically I pass the data from create component to show component via a service called Shared service. The data am passing (response from the backend is an array of Javascript objects).

the problem is that the data is not reaching the show component, since I want after it reaches the show component I want to loop through the array of objects and show them on the view (show.component.html) as a table

Please assist?

**Create Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { SharedService } from 'src/app/Services/shared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create',
  templateUrl: './create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create.component.css']
})
export class CreateComponent implements OnInit {

  public form = {
    sponsorFirstName: null,
    sponsorSurName: null,
    sponsorEmail: null,
    sponsorPhone: null,
    nationality: null,
    childFirstName: null,
    childAge: null,
    childSurName: null,
    childGender: null
  };

  public error = null;

  constructor(
       private router: Router,
       private Shared : SharedService) { }

   onSubmit(){
    this.Auth.submitFormData(this.form).subscribe(
      data => this.handleResponse(data),
      error => this.handleError(error)
    );
  }

  handleResponse(data){
    //console.log(data.data);
    //pass the data to the shared service
    this.Shared.createData(data.data);
    //redirect to show-data component whereby I show the data in a table
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/show-data');
  }

  handleError(error){
      this.error = error.error.errors;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**Shared service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { TokenService } from './token.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {

    private userData = new BehaviorSubject;
    checkUser$ = this.userData.asObservable();

    createData(data:any){
       this.userData.next(data);
    }

    constructor(private Token : TokenService) { }
}
```

**Show.component.ts file**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from 'src/app/Services/shared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-show',
  templateUrl: './show.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./show.component.css']
})
export class ShowComponent implements OnInit {

  public userData;

  constructor(
    private Shared : SharedService,
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.Shared.checkUser$.subscribe(message => this.userData = message);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a race condition between the service and your component, you should try and instantiate `userData` with a `ReplaySubject(1)` like so:

`private userData = new ReplaySubject(1);`

This way your subject will have a buffer and even if you late subscribe to it you'll have the value.

> ReplaySubject
>
> A Subject that "replays" or emits old values to new
> subscribers

Comment: are you providing the `SharedService` only once in root module?